# Message: Using $this when not in object context codeigniter 3

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, model, codeigniter-3

I want to access my database models from database.php file.

`

```
//$ci =& get_instance();
        $this->CI->session->userdata('user_id');
        $this->CI->load->model('users/user_model');
        $current_user = $this->CI->user_model->find($this->CI->auth->user_id());
        echo $current_user->organisation;
        $this->CI->load->model('organisation/organisation_model');
        $org =  $this->CI->organisation_model->find($current_user->organisation);
```

`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uncomment your first line

`$ci =& get_instance();`

Then use $ci instead of $this like this

`$ci->session->userdata('user_id');`

Comment: Thank you! Note that i had to load session library: $CI->load->library('session');

Answer (score 0):

**Please use the below code, to access the database model or queries.**

```
$CI = & get_instance();
$CI->session->userdata('user_id');
$CI->load->model('users/user_model');
$current_user = $CI->user_model->find($CI->auth->user_id());
echo $current_user->organisation;
$CI->load->model('organisation/organisation_model');
$org =  $CI->organisation_model->find($current_user->organisation);
```

Comment: Thank you that's correct! theere no space between '=' and '&' at the first line

Comment: @saghirSAGHIR it will work with space as well.